# Visual Studio Agents 2012 on Server 2003 SP2

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I'm attempting to build out our Lab Manager with TFS 2012.  On a virtual machine running Server 2003 SP2 32bit, I'm attempting to install the Visual Studio Agents 2012 and am running into an error:

```
Setup Failed!
Install cannot continue because some required components failed. 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
Asia
```

Looking into it, the install log is erroring when it's attempting to install dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe component.  Looking at that install log, it is failing with:

```
The .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating system.
```

So, I see according to the [Agents 2012 MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127.aspx), that Server 2003 SP2 is supported by Agents 2012.  But I also see that according to the [.NET 4.5 MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx), Server 2003 isn't supported.

So how do I install Agents 2012 on 2003 SP2 as the documentation implies I can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm very sorry that we made a mistake in the MSDN documentation here. The correct list of supported operating systems is on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh546459.aspx) and it doesn't include Windows Server 2003. We will fix the mistaken page in the next two weeks.

Once again, I'm sorry for the mistake here, as I realize you'll have spent time on it.

Comment: Alan seem to be a genuine Microsoft employee; it doesn't get much more official than this.